Tailwind addVariant typing
I'm trying to type Tailwind's config file but I can't get it right for the life of me. It looks correct to me and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Here's my code:
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";
import formsPlugin from "@tailwindcss/forms";
import plugin from "tailwindcss/plugin";

interface Props {
  modifySelectors: (className: string) => string;
  separator: string;
}
interface modifySelectorsProps {
  className: string;
}

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/layouts/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}"
  ],
  plugins: [
    formsPlugin,
    plugin(({ addVariant, e }) => {
      addVariant("label-checked", ({ modifySelectors, separator }: Props) => {
        modifySelectors(({ className }: modifySelectorsProps) => {
          const eClassName = e(`label-checked${separator}${className}`);
          const yourSelector = 'input[type="radio"]';
          return `${yourSelector}:checked ~ .${eClassName}`;
        });
      });
    })
  ]
};
export default config;


For the addVariant line, I'm getting this error:
Argument of type '({ modifySelectors, separator }: Props) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | string[] | (() => string) | (() => string)[]'.
  Type '({ modifySelectors, separator }: Props) => void' is not assignable to type '() => string'.
    Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 1 or more, but got 0.ts(2345)

Even though I'm declaring that it expects the className parameter.
And for the modifySelectors line, I'm getting:
Argument of type '({ className }: modifySelectorsProps) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)

This one goes away if I keep this type and remove the type from the line above.

You have contradicted yourself. Props.modifySelectors takes a string but you  are passing it a function. There are other mistakes as well.

How do you think you are supposed to call addVariant? What documentation have you read that tells you you can call it like that? Because you are passing it a value that it doesn't support. And that's what the type error is saying.

@AlexWayne here's one of the examples I used for addVariant: https://dev.to/devdevcharlie/writing-a-tailwindcss-variant-plugin-2oe2

That plugin uses tailwind v2. Tailwind v3 changed it's plugin API. See my new answer.

It looks like you are using the tailwind v2 API for plugins, which changed in v3.

Version 2 docs.
Version 3 docs.

You'll need to make this plugin use the version 3 plugin API to make your plugin work with modern tailwind installations

Thanks, this is the route I ended up taking and it did the trick.

For anyone else looking for these types, looking in the tailwind config.d.ts shows a type for the function fed in for the plugins array where the function takes in PluginAPI as the parameter.
plugins: [
    function ({ addVariant }: PluginAPI) {
      addVariant('not-disabled', '&:not(:disabled)')
    },
],

